# Stamina stopped generating suddenly

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I was going through Blackreach fighting off some Chaurus hunters, etc, when suddenly, my stamina stopped recharging! 
I tried checking active effects but did not notice anything labeled in red, nor do I have some sort of disease ... What could have caused this?

Platform : Xbox360

Comment: Might be worth visiting a shrine to get a blessing and try sleeping it off. Have you tried equipping some +stamina regen items to see if it's the regen?

Comment: Yep, but as soon as the effect wears off, stamina stops regenerating. An I have the blood of a werewolf, so sleeping does not give any bonus..

Comment: I assume you've checked all your gear for -regen and unequipped it all to see if start regen again?

Comment: Yeah I did. It happened by a sudden glitch where an elevator from Blackreach took me back to skyrim, then the screen dimmed again and repeated the process of transporting me back up.. I had to jump as soon as I was able to in order to cancel the loop. Then my stamina stopped regenerating .. weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a vampire? Vampires stop generating Stamina when in sunlight, in vanilla Skyrim (vanilla = no mods for that)

You said you don't have a disease, so I guess it depends on if you define vampirism as a disease. I think of it as an asset. I love vampires.

EDIT: sounds like a glitch. However, it's possible that you have a disease and didn't know it. You can check to see if anything is directly causing this by going into your Magicka menu screen and the last category shows your current effects. If nothing is showing there then it is a glitch.

**Two solutions if it is a glitch:**
a) save and restart the game
b) if glitch still occurs then just keep reverting to a previous save until you find a save that is not corrupted and your stamina regenerates.

Comment: Yeah thats what I did, just reverted to an older save. I am a werewolf so I cannot have any disease !